# Dynamic check box with import!

Tags: dynamic, import

Here what i am trying to do:

I have a list of the names of excel files, for example

`s={"red carpet.csv","red box.csv","black carpet.csv","black box.csv"};`

i am selecting the csv files with the name red(for example) by doing

```
`selectfromAll=Select[s, StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "red" ~~ ___] &];`
```

Now i want to create a dynamic box using this command, the output in this example is two check box : "red carpet.csv" and "red box.csv"

`a=CheckboxBar[Dynamic[selected], SelectfromAll,  Appearance -> "Vertical"]`

I want to select one or the two check box, then use the information to import this two excels files, like for example

`Import[Ifchecked(a)]`

Hope my description is clear

Any suggestions?

thx in advance

Comment: You'll need a Button or similar to indicate that the user interaction with the `CheckboxBar[]` has finished

Comment: Any idea how to manage that?
I am kind of new to the gui in mathematica!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = FileNames["C:\\*.csv"];
selectfromAll = Select[s, StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "rob" ~~ ___] &]
Pane[Column[{CheckboxBar[Dynamic[selected], selectfromAll, Appearance -> "Vertical"], 
     Dynamic[selected], 
     Button["Import", imported = Import /@ selected]}]]
```